# Editing a label in "new individual" form

Tags: contacts, webform-civicrm, forms, contact-view, quickform

I want to edit a field called "source" in the new Individual form. I want to change the name of the field. where can I change it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the word replacements feature, if you want to replace the word everywhere.

Or if you're just using that field for a different purpose, create a new custom field instead.

Comment: not everywhere, only in one place

Comment: and I have a problem in word replacements as well. It is not getting replaced in all places. Tried replacing "contributions" with "donations". the change is not getting reflected in CiviReport, while in other places it is changing.

Answer (score 3):

Try some CSS:

```
label[for=contact_source]
{
    /* ...definitions here... */
}
```

You can use the ::after to add arbitrary text, as per, e.g. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: Do you mean javascript/jquery?

Comment: I was thinking ::before or ::after

Answer (score 2):

You already had many answers how to. I will make a recommendation: create a custom field rather than manipulate a core CiviCRM field? It will be easier to maintain if fields change in updates of CiviCRM.

Comment: I want to do the same thing that field  label "Source" does... It tracks the source of the contact from events.. Apart from events my organization has contacts from website, Stall, etc. I want to add values to the field like Website visitor, Stall visitor. But the Label "Source" is not self evident.

Comment: It is a recommendation :-) feel free to change the label with jQuery or css

Comment: I think I'm with Erik on this one - a custom field is going to be a better strategy. Aside from the maintainability, another reason is that you have more control over the field if it's a custom field - e.g. you can set up a select for it, and it won't get auto-populated by various internal mechanisms.